# Integration with facebook for each activity

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on a recipes app and I have two questions:

1. I have 50 activities, one for each recipe. Either I have to write code on each activity for sharing on facebook or just on main activity.
2. I want that when I click on share button my recipe will post on facebook but now when I click on share button it goes on simple post option for posting status or image.

Here is my code for sharing:

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beef_r1);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://comexample.sairamkrishna.myapplication/*");

                try {
                    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(screenshotUri);
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "I have 50 activities for each recipe" - Have you created 50 classes to show each recipe?

Comment: yes Sir 1 class for 1 recipe

Comment: qasim: your questions are not very clear. Can you elaborate on what problems/behaviors you're currently seeing and on what you'd like to see instead?